# Can't get armenian months names

Tags: java, localization, calendar, locale

I want to print armenian month names but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
Locale loc = new Locale("hy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(loc);
System.out.println(cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG_STANDALONE, loc));
```

I have tried many others abbreviation like "hye" or "arm", but nothing works. Other language such as russian "ru" work fine. I have no idee what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an [enhancement in JDK8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.8.html#cldr)  wherein the CLDR's XML-based locale data has been incorporated into the JDK 8 release, however it is disabled by default.
So, if you run your code with the argument `-Djava.locale.providers=CLDR` or add the same through the `java.locale.providers` `System.property` in your code, `hy: Armenian hy_AM: Armenian` will be supported.

With [JDK 9 enhancements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/intl/internationalization-enhancements-jdk-9.htm#JSINT-GUID-9DCDB41C-A989-4220-8140-DBFB844A0FCA)  , CLDR locale data is enabled by default. So, the code will run without adding any system property.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

After browsing Oracles Website I've found a list of supported languages and Locale_IDs. As it seems the language you want is not supported by JDK7 Locale.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html

Answer (score 1):

This language is not supported, but you can create your own locale by following [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html) guide.

This is the javadoc of `Locale.Builder`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.Builder.html

Comment: How does creating a `Locale`-object create missing text resources, too?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Then please show me and others how to feed the `Locale.Builder` with any informations about Armenian month names (what the OP finally wants to achieve). I have not seen any hint about this subject in the API. My impression is: Your answer is not really related to the question of OP.

Comment: I would not write a ready-to-implement code by 0, and also other answers have pointed out that there are many other ways to implements this. So yes, at this time of the question evolution is not related my answer anymore.

Answer (score 1):

With the following code you can print out all supported `Calendar` locales (sorted by languageTag):

```
Locale[] locales = Calendar.getAvailableLocales();
Arrays.sort(locales, Comparator.comparing(Locale::toLanguageTag));
for (Locale locale : locales)
    System.out.print(" " + locale.toLanguageTag());
```

Unfortunately, in my Oracle Java 8, there is no Armenian locale (beginning with "hy") in this list.

> ar ar-AE ar-BH ar-DZ ar-EG ar-IQ ar-JO ar-KW ar-LB ar-LY ar-MA ar-OM ar-QA ar-SA ar-SD ar-SY ar-TN ar-YE be be-BY bg bg-BG ca ca-ES cs cs-CZ da da-DK de de-AT de-CH de-DE de-GR de-LU el el-CY el-GR en en-AU en-CA en-GB en-IE en-IN en-MT en-NZ en-PH en-SG en-US en-ZA es es-AR es-BO es-CL es-CO es-CR es-CU es-DO es-EC es-ES es-GT es-HN es-MX es-NI es-PA es-PE es-PR es-PY es-SV es-US es-UY es-VE et et-EE fi fi-FI fr fr-BE fr-CA fr-CH fr-FR fr-LU ga ga-IE he he-IL hi hi-IN hr hr-HR hu hu-HU id id-ID is is-IS it it-CH it-IT ja ja-JP ja-JP-u-ca-japanese-x-lvariant-JP ko ko-KR lt lt-LT lv lv-LV mk mk-MK ms ms-MY mt mt-MT nl nl-BE nl-NL nn-NO no no-NO pl pl-PL pt pt-BR pt-PT ro ro-RO ru ru-RU sk sk-SK sl sl-SI sq sq-AL sr sr-BA sr-CS sr-Latn sr-Latn-BA sr-Latn-ME sr-Latn-RS sr-ME sr-RS sv sv-SE th th-TH th-TH-u-nu-thai-x-lvariant-TH tr tr-TR uk uk-UA und vi vi-VN zh zh-CN zh-HK zh-SG zh-TW

#### Edit:

With Oracle Java 8 and additional option `-Djava.locale.providers=CLDR` as suggested in 
[Pallavi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43228492/cant-get-armenian-months-names/43229132#43229132)
the resulting list contains the Armenian locale ("hy"):

> aa af af-NA agq ak am ar ar-AE ar-BH ar-DZ ar-EG ar-IQ ar-JO ar-KW ar-LB ar-LY ar-MA ar-OM ar-QA ar-SA ar-SD ar-SY ar-TN ar-YE as asa az az-Cyrl bas be be-BY bem bez bg bg-BG bm bn bn-IN bo br brx bs byn ca ca-ES cgg chr cs cs-CZ cy da da-DK dav de de-AT de-CH de-DE de-GR de-LI de-LU dje dua dyo dz ebu ee el el-CY el-GR en en-AU en-BE en-BW en-BZ en-CA en-Dsrt en-GB en-HK en-IE en-IN en-JM en-MT en-NA en-NZ en-PH en-PK en-SG en-TT en-US en-US-POSIX en-ZA en-ZW eo es es-419 es-AR es-BO es-CL es-CO es-CR es-CU es-DO es-EC es-ES es-GQ es-GT es-HN es-MX es-NI es-PA es-PE es-PR es-PY es-SV es-US es-UY es-VE et et-EE eu ewo fa fa-AF ff fi fi-FI fil fo fr fr-BE fr-CA fr-CH fr-FR fr-LU fur ga ga-IE gd gl gsw gu guz gv ha haw he he-IL hi hi-IN hr hr-HR hu hu-HU hy ia id id-ID ig ii is is-IS it it-CH it-IT ja ja-JP ja-JP-u-ca-japanese-x-lvariant-JP jmc ka kab kam kde kea khq ki kk kl kln km kn ko ko-KR kok ksb ksf ksh kw lag lg ln lo lt lt-LT lu luo luy lv lv-LV mas mer mfe mg mgh mk mk-MK ml mr ms ms-BN ms-MY mt mt-MT mua my naq nb nd ne ne-IN nl nl-BE nl-NL nmg nn nn-NO no no-NO nr nso nus nyn om or pa pa-Arab pl pl-PL ps pt pt-BR pt-PT rm rn ro ro-RO rof ru ru-RU ru-UA rw rwk saq sbp se seh ses sg shi shi-Tfng si sk sk-SK sl sl-SI sn so sq sq-AL sr sr-BA sr-CS sr-Cyrl-BA sr-Latn sr-Latn-BA sr-Latn-ME sr-Latn-RS sr-ME sr-RS ss ssy st sv sv-FI sv-SE sw sw-KE swc ta te teo th th-TH th-TH-u-nu-thai-x-lvariant-TH ti ti-ER tig tn to tr tr-TR ts twq tzm uk uk-UA und ur ur-IN uz uz-Arab uz-Latn vai vai-Latn ve vi vi-VN vun wae wal xh xog yav yo zh zh-CN zh-HK zh-Hans-HK zh-Hans-MO zh-Hans-SG zh-Hant zh-Hant-HK zh-Hant-MO zh-SG zh-TW zu

Comment: Did you run your code with the argument -Djava.locale.providers=CLDR as suggested in my answer ? You will definitely see hy in the list then.

Comment: @Pallavi I ran my code without this option. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Pallavi is correct for Java-8 and Java-9.

However, if you are on **Java-7**, then you could set up your own [DateFormatSymbolsProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/spi/DateFormatSymbolsProvider.html) specialized for Armenian language via the [service loader mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/spi/LocaleServiceProvider.html).

You will need a file within META-INF/services-subdirectory like with exactly this name:

```
META-INF/services/java.text.spi.DateFormatSymbolsProvider
```

And the content of this file should contain a line like this (please adjust the names to your real implementation class of service provider mentioned above):

```
mypackage.MyImplementationOfDateFormatSymbolsProvider
```

As soon as you have created an appropriate jar-library with this META-INF-substructure included, the new service provider for Armenian will be queried, too.

About the required text resources, I have imported the CLDR-v30-resources into my own library Time4J. Maybe you can take profit from the [resource file](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J/blob/master/i18n/src/main/resources/names/iso8601_hy.properties) for Armenian (also containing standalone-forms for month names) and use a part of the content for your own service provider.